# How can we retrieve data from Kafka state store using micronaut Kafka?

Tags: micronaut

I don't see any sample example or document for interactive queries in micronaut Kafka. Appreciate if someone can help on this.

Something similar to - 
https://kafka.apache.org/10/documentation/streams/developer-guide/interactive-queries.html#querying-local-key-value-stores

https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka/blob/master/spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka-streams/src/main/java/org/springframework/cloud/stream/binder/kafka/streams/InteractiveQueryService.java

Comment: https://github.com/micronaut-projects/micronaut-kafka

Comment: Sorry, I corrected my question. I am looking for InteractiveQuery Services equivalent in Micronaut.